# Mailchimp API 2.0 Subscribing users with groups - checkbox value

Tags: php, api, mailchimp

I am stuck on how to retrieve and send the value of my checkbox in a Mailchimp form using the API 2.0.
At the end of my form I have this checkbox

```
 <input type="checkbox" checked data-dojo-type="dijit/form/CheckBox" id="group_1" name="group[4909][1]" value="1"  class="av-checkbox"><span id="message-check">YES, I agree to be contacted by ... for promotions and special offers.</span>
```

here my php code to connect and send data through the API:

```
$email = array('email' => htmlentities($_REQUEST['MERGE0']));
$merge_vars = array(
'MMERGE3' => $_REQUEST['MERGE3'], //Voucher value
'MMERGE4' => $_REQUEST['MERGE4'], //Date value
'MMERGE6' => $_REQUEST['MERGE6'],  //Sales Person value
'FNAME' => $_REQUEST['MERGE1'],   //First Name value
'LNAME' => $_REQUEST['MERGE2'],   //Last Name value
'MMERGE5' => $_REQUEST['MERGE5'], //Phone value
'groupings' => array(
    'id' => '4909',
    'name' => "Offers",
    'groups' => $_REQUEST['group']
    )
);
require('Mailchimp.php');
$Mailchimp = new Mailchimp( $api_key );
$Mailchimp_Lists = new Mailchimp_Lists( $Mailchimp );
$subscriber = $Mailchimp_Lists->subscribe($list_id, $email,  $merge_vars, $email_type, $double_optin);
```

I followed this documentation https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/subscribe.php

All the fields Voucher, date,sales,first and last name and Phone are sent and the user is subscribed on my list. The only value i am missing is the checkbox. I would like to send at least "Yes" or "1" to my list for that checkbox.
Cannot figure out!

Any suggestion guys?

Thanks.
Vince.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK 1h later of posting my problem i found the solution.

Here the correct code that works for me:

```
$merge_vars = array(
'MMERGE3' => $_REQUEST['MERGE3'], //Voucher value
'MMERGE4' => $_REQUEST['MERGE4'], //Date value
'MMERGE6' => $_REQUEST['MERGE6'],  //Sales Person value
'FNAME' => $_REQUEST['MERGE1'],   //First Name value
'LNAME' => $_REQUEST['MERGE2'],   //Last Name value
'MMERGE5' => $_REQUEST['MERGE5'], //Phone value
'GROUPINGS' => array(
    0 => array(
        'id' => '4909', // need grouping ID
        'groups' => array( 'YES, I agree to be contacted by ... for promotions and special offers.' )
    )
),
);
```

In other words I printed out my group id that i have in my list:

```
//Print the current group of a list
/*$current_groupings = $Mailchimp->call( 'lists/interest-groupings', array(
            'id' => 'your_list_ID',
        ) );
var_dump($current_groupings);*/
```

I got the entire array of group:

```
array(1) { 
[0]=> array(5) {
    ["id"]=> int(4909) 
    ["name"]=> string(6) "Offers" 
    ["form_field"]=> string(10) "checkboxes" 
    ["display_order"]=> string(1) "0" 
    ["groups"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> array(5) { 
            ["id"]=> int(17445) 
            ["bit"]=> string(1) "1" 
            ["name"]=> string(89) "YES, I agree to be contacted by ... for promotions and special offers." 
            ["display_order"]=> string(1) "1" 
            ["subscribers"]=> NULL 
        } 
    } 
} 
}
```

Therefore it was really easy to understand that I need to use:

1. Group ID in this case 4909
2. and the groups name that in this case is: "YES, I agree to be contacted by ... for promotions and special offers."

That's it. Works! 
Hope this help someone else.

Cheers,
Vince.

Comment: For me I couldn't get the grouping ID to work but it worked to use it's name instead.